# Numba Rotation Matrix with Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numba

I'm trying to use Numba to accelerate some functions, in particular a function that performs a 3D rotation given three angles, as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def rotation_matrix(theta_x, theta_y, theta_z):
    # Convert to radians. To ensure counter-clockwise (ccw) rotations, take
    # negative of angles.
    theta_x_rad = -np.radians(theta_x)
    theta_y_rad = -np.radians(theta_y)
    theta_z_rad = -np.radians(theta_z)
    # Define rotation matrices (yaw, pitch, roll)
    Rx = np.array([[1, 0,0],
                    [0, np.cos(theta_x_rad),-np.sin(theta_x_rad)],
                    [0, np.sin(theta_x_rad),np.cos(theta_x_rad) ]
                    ])


    Ry = np.array([[ np.cos(theta_y_rad), 0,np.sin(theta_y_rad)],
                    [ 0,1,0],
                    [-np.sin(theta_y_rad), 0,np.cos(theta_y_rad)]
                    ])


    Rz = np.array([[np.cos(theta_z_rad),-np.sin(theta_z_rad),0],
                    [np.sin(theta_z_rad),np.cos(theta_z_rad),0],
                    [0,0,1]
                    ])


    # Compute total rotation matrix
    R  = np.dot(Rz, np.dot( Ry, Rx ))
    #
    return R
```

The function is relatively simple, but when Numba calls it, it throws an error when I try to define `Rx`.It appears that Numba has a problem with multidimensional arrays (?).  I'm not sure how to modify this such that Numba could utilize it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've never used numba, (only Cython to speed things up), so this might be a bit off, but why are you trying to use it here in the first place? You are only doing numpy operations which are typically already as fast as you can get. If you have to call this function in a loop many times, you're probably much better off by creating a unique numpy array of shape (N, 3, 3) with all the 3x3 matrices stacked and use `np.dot` on these tensors instead?

Comment: This function is called by other functions in my script, however when it is called, Numba throws the error. The issue is not with speed, but why Numba doesn't like this function.

Comment: Try replacing `0` with `0.0` and `1` with `1.0` in definitions of `Rx, Ry` and `Rz`.

Comment: Ok sorry then I can't really help. Again my experience is only with Cython, and there I would avoid any non-python objects (like numpy here), because they would be unsupported or anyway not easy to work with. You could certainly refactor your code by writing the operations by hand (np.radians is just `* pi/180`, cos and sin are in the `math` package, dot products of 3x3 matrices are longer but easy to write), but it certainly will make the code less readable

Comment: Or you can pass `dtype=np.float32` or `dtype=np.float64` to `np.array` defining each of `Rx, Ry` or `Rz`. For a list of currently supported types, you can refer [here.](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.43.0/reference/numpysupported.html#scalar-types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the **mix between integers and floats typed values**. Numba try to defined a type of the array and found that `[1, 0, 0]` is a list of integer but the overall array is initialized with both a list of integer and a list of floats. The type inference is confused and raised an error because *the overall type is ambiguous*. You can write `1.0` and `0.0` instead of `1` and `0` so to fix the issue. More generally, specifying the `dtype` of arrays is generally a good practice, especially in Numba due to the *type inference*.

If you want to avoid compilation errors at runtime when the function is called the first time, then you can precise the parameter types. Note that you can use `njit` instead of `nopython=True` (shorter). The resulting decorator should be `@njit('(float64, float64, float64)')`.

Comment: Conversion from int to float worked.  Thank you for this explanation.